# Function like Num a => a -> Text without String transformation

Tags: haskell, text

I have heard that the usage of [show and read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437824/common-knowledge-on-haskell-performance) is a bottleneck in the program. Is there a function like this which doesn't involve string transformation:

```
thow :: Num a => a -> Text
thow = undefined
```

One obvious implementation is like this `pack . show` but unfortunately that involves string conversion. Is there any optimal way for achieving this ?

Comment: In this general form: No. But for a concrete type (say, `Integer -> Text`), maybe. Which is it you need?

Comment: Neither `Num a => a -> Text` nor `Num a => a -> String` can be implemented. Why would you want to do this, by the way? How would you use `thow`?

Comment: Rhymoid: That’s not right. `Show` is a superclass of `Num`, so `show :: Num a => a -> String`. Or at least it used to be the case...

Comment: @JoachimBreitner I would be happy even with a concrete type. Is it achievable for `Integer -> Text` ?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: wait, hasn't `Show` been removed as a superclass of `Num`?

Comment: Guess hayoo is still on an older version. So we are both right :-)

Comment: @Rhymoid Interesting. Was there any reason for removing `Show` ?

Comment: @Sibi: There's no good reason to depend on `Eq` or `Show`. `Eq` is involved in literal patterns, but I don't think that's such a useful feature to bake into `Num`. The functionality in `Show` is completely disjoint from `Num`'s. The real problem is that you can't create more abstract instances, like `instance Num a => Num (z -> a)`, because functions can neither be shown nor compared.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking through the docs of the `text` package, you probably want to use the functions in [`Data.Text.Lazy.Builder.Int`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text/docs/Data-Text-Lazy-Builder-Int.html), e.g.:

```
thow :: Integral a => a -> Text
thow = toLazyText . decimal
```

If you look at the code of that module you see that it has `RULES` and `SPECIALIZE` pragmas in place to optimize this, if `a` is one of the common integral types.

Answer (score 3):

The [double-conversion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/double-conversion) package does this for `Float` and `Double`, and is highly optimized.  I doubt you'd be able to match its performance with a polymorphic function (although you could always specialize with a RULE).

Comment: Note that `Data.Text.Lazy.Build.Int` also has that; I extended my answer.

Comment: By "that", I presume you mean RULES and not conversions for `Float` and `Double` (those are available in `Data.Text.Lazy.Builder.RealFloat`.  Those certainly work, although IIRC they're less efficient than `double-conversion`.  Better than `show` though.