# Can C++ program string search as fast as and/or faster than python?

Tags: python, c++, regex, benchmarking, string-search

I'm not sure why I'm having easier time string searching in program I wrote in python faster than a program I wrote in C++. Is there a trick I'm missing?

**Generating Use Case**

This is for a single line use case, however in the real use case I care about multiple lines.

```
#include "tchar.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
void main(void){
   ofstream testfile;
   unsigned int line_idx = 0;
   testfile.open("testfile.txt");
   for(line_idx = 0; line_idx < 50000u; line_idx++)
   {
      if(line_idx != 43268u )
      {
        testfile << line_idx << " dontcare" << std::endl;
      }
      else
      {
        testfile << line_idx << " care" << std::endl;
      }
   }
   testfile.close();
}
```

**The regular expression**
Using regular expression `^(\d*)\s(care)$`

**The C++ Program** takes 13.954 seconds

```
#include "tchar.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void main(void){
   double duration;
   std::clock_t start;
   ifstream testfile("testfile.txt", ios_base::in);
   unsigned int line_idx = 0;
   bool found = false;
   string line;
   regex ptrn("^(\\d*)\\s(care)$");

   start = std::clock();   /* Debug time */
   while (getline(testfile, line)) 
   {
      std::smatch matches;
      if(regex_search(line, matches, ptrn))
      {
         found = true;
      }
   }
   testfile.close();
   duration = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   std::cout << "Found? " << (found ? "yes" : "no") << std::endl;
   std::cout << " Total time: " <<  duration << std::endl;
}
```

**Python Program** takes 0.02200 seconds

```
import sys, os       # to navigate and open files
import re            # to search file
import time          # to benchmark

ptrn  = re.compile(r'^(\d*)\s(care)$', re.MULTILINE)

start = time.time()
with open('testfile.txt','r') as testfile:
   filetext = testfile.read()
   matches = re.findall(ptrn, filetext)
   print("Found? " + "Yes" if len(matches) == 1 else "No")

end = time.time()
print("Total time", end - start)
```

Comment: try to `break` when you found a match in your C++ loop...

Comment: also declare `std::smatch matches;` outside the loop to avoid it being constructed over and over

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, it's applicable in this use case, but it's not the same for the real use case becuase there are multiple lines I care about. I'll update question

Comment: other difference: you're performing only 1 call to regex in python because you're reading all the file at once. With C++ code you're calling it once per line.

Comment: 13 seconds there's clearly a problem!

Comment: what flags did you use to compile?  Somehow everyone always thinks that debug builds should be fast in c++....

Comment: the `getline` also performs a lot of string allocation/copies. Try to make your C++ code as close as possible as the python code first.

Comment: Can you just try something like this for reading [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring

Comment: Which compiler do you use? I tried g++ and it gave me 0.042s on your code with no modifications except g++-specific fixes like `int main`

Comment: @Ratah, great! brought it down to 8.923 seconds

Comment: @DenisSheremet Visual Studio

Comment: @UKMonkey I think you're right, I'm in debug mode, no opitmizaiton. Need to resolve some release mode errors before testing it

Comment: I've closed the question, as it seems a related problem. Don't hesitate to [edit] it if you still have unsolved issues and tell me so I can reopen (or not ;))

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, Thanks  this was resolved thanks to UKMonkey, and props for Ratah for imporvement

Comment: One of the biggest differences is due to the less efficient regex implementation on VS. By using [`boost::regex`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14205096/1460794) the time went from 0.052 down to 0.005 for C++ vs 0.024 for Python.

Comment: There are many different regex libraries for C and C++, with different featuresets and different strategies. Performance varies wildly depending on which library, what regex you have, what the input looks like, and if you apply the regex line by line or just have it scan the whole input in one go. Also, be aware that in most cases, the regex will be compiled before you use it to match some input, and that the compilation time itself can be substantial, which matters if you only do a few searches with a given regex.

Comment: Please post the solution as an **answer**, not as a question edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Implemented Ratah's recommendation to 8.923**

about 5 seconds improvement, by reading file to single string

```
   double duration;
   std::clock_t start;
   ifstream testfile("testfile.txt", ios_base::in);
   unsigned int line_idx = 0;
   bool found = false;
   string line;
   regex ptrn("^(\\d*)\\s(care)$");
   std::smatch matches;

   start = std::clock();   /* Debug time */
   std::string test_str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(testfile)),
                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

   if(regex_search(test_str, matches, ptrn))
   {
      found = true;
   }
   testfile.close();
   duration = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   std::cout << "Found? " << (found ? "yes" : "no") << std::endl;
   std::cout << " Total time: " <<  duration << std::endl;
```

**After UKMonkey's note, reconfigured project to release which also includes \O2 and brought it down to 0.086 seconds**

Thanks to Jean-Francois Fabre, Ratah, UKMonkey