# regex performance java vs c++11

Tags: java, c++, regex, performance, c++11

I am learning regex in c++ and java. So i did a performance test on c++11 regex and java regex with same expression and same no of inputs. Strangely java regex is faster than c++11 regex. Is there anything wrong in my code? Pls correct me

Java code:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main {
    private final static int MAX = 1_000_000;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[\\w._]+@\\w+\\.[a-zA-Z]+$");
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
            p.matcher("abcd_ed123.t12y@haha.com").matches();
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.print(end-start);
    }
}
```

C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long start = GetTickCount64();
    regex pat("^[\\w._]+@\\w+\\.[a-zA-Z]+$");
    for (long i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        regex_match("abcd_ed123.t12y@haha.com", pat);
    }
    long long end = GetTickCount64();
    cout << end - start;
    return 0;
}
```

Performance:

```
Java -> 1003ms
C++  -> 124360ms
```

Comment: Obvious question: How did you compile the c++ code? Did you have optimizations on?

Comment: So you conclude that there's something wrong with your code because Java performs better than C++?

Comment: Please confirm you coumpiled your C++ code with optimizations turned on. Also, you're not measuring just the regex, you're also measuring the print statement. I would not consider this a valid test.

Comment: i think it is because `std::regex` aren't precompiled meening that the regex and the expression to check are parsed at run-time

Comment: Try it without printing the result to get the true value of the regex runtimes. Also, is the regex compiled on the C++ side?

Comment: how did you measure? I have the feeling that the numbers you quote primariliy reflect the time your code needs to print something on the console and the time needed for the regex is just some noise on top of that

Comment: @user463035818 The "measuring code" is in the question...

Comment: @Borgleader ups, then my feeling was right ;)

Comment: i use visual studio17 for compiling c++

Comment: Did you time a Debug or Release build? There can be a significant performance difference between them (Release enables optimizations).

Comment: Right! In Release build I get 1672ms for VS2017.

Comment: i think i have problem in my VS build settings. what should i change?? or can u tell me the command line compilation code.

Comment: Downvoters it would be nice if u give a solution.

Comment: In release build I get no output at all for GCC. In case it helps: here's the hotspot JVM assembly output [from `LD_PRELOAD=/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/fcml-1.1.3/example/hsdis/.libs/libhsdis-amd64.so ./jre1.8.0_171/bin/java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintAssembly Main  2>&1 > disasm.a`](http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/fea76143-b712-4df9-97c3-4725b2f9e695/disasm.a.xz)

Comment: This is going to depend on the regex engine. The one in `GCC` for example is not the fastest. Try it with `PCRE` (pcrecpp) and it should be a great deal faster.

Comment: In my tests, `GCC` regex is 20% slower than the `Java` one but using `PCRE` regex is 3 times *faster* that the `Java` test.

Comment: The MSVC regex implementation is [notoriously slow and in need of an overhaul](https://twitter.com/StephanTLavavej/status/958129309130014720). A Better comparison would be boost::regex.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/14229152/332733

Comment: And LLVM's libc++'s std::regex is even faster (2x) than boost regex in my tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to add to the already provided answers...

Yes, the C++11 `std::regex` is slightly slower (even in Release mode) than the Java one.

But PCRE2 with JIT is 3 times faster:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#define PCRE2_STATIC
#define PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH 8
#include "pcre2.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main()
{
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    int errn;
    PCRE2_SIZE erroffset;
    auto pattern = (PCRE2_SPTR8)"^[\\w._]+@\\w+\\.[a-zA-Z]+$";
    pcre2_code* re = pcre2_compile(pattern, PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED, 0, &errn, &erroffset, nullptr);
    if (!re)
        cerr << "pcre2_compile failed\n";
    pcre2_match_data* match_data = pcre2_match_data_create_from_pattern(re, nullptr);
    for (long i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        auto text = (PCRE2_SPTR8)"abcd_ed123.t12y@haha.com";
        int rc = pcre2_match(re, text, PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED, 0, 0, match_data, nullptr);
        if (rc <= 0)
            cerr << "pcre2_match failed\n";
    }
    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << (end - start) / 1ms << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**Results:**

- PCRE2 v10.21: `139ms`
- Java: `440ms`

Comment: "JIT" implies PCRE does compile directly into machine instructions? From what I've seen regex usually compile into DFA, with the engine being highly optimized, but clearly ahead-of-time compiled code. +1 for the data point

Comment: @sehe yes, it compiles [directly](https://github.com/luvit/pcre2/tree/master/src/sljit) into machine instructions. Kind of hard to beat

Comment: TIL. Awesome library. Nice addition!

Answer (score 16):

Made the C++ sample portable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <regex>

using C = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main()
{
    auto start = C::now();
    std::regex pat("^[\\w._]+@\\w+\\.[a-zA-Z]+$");
    for (long i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        regex_match("abcd_ed123.t12y@haha.com", pat);
    }
    std::cout << (C::now() - start)/1.0ms;
}
```

On linux, and with `clang++ -std=c++14 -march=native -O3 -o clang ./test.cpp` I get `595.970 ms`. See also **<kbd>[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/seyy4DD0ZTruAe6q)</kbd>**

The java runs in `561 ms`, on the same machine.

> **Update**: Boost Regex runs much faster, see below comparative benchmark

> **Caveat**: synthetic benchmarks like these are very prone to error: the compiler might sense that no observable side effects are done, and optimize the whole loop out, just to give an example.

### More Fun: Adding Boost To The Mix

Using [Boost 1.67](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_67_0.html) and [Nonius Micro-Benchmarking Framework](https://nonius.io/)

[image]

We can see that Boost's Regex implementations are *considerably* faster.

See the detailed sample data interactive online: https://plot.ly/~sehe/25/

**<kbd>[Code Used](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JVBY2ZxBjJ/)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/xpressive/xpressive_static.hpp>
#define NONIUS_RUNNER
#include <nonius/benchmark.h++>
#include <nonius/main.h++>

template <typename Re>
void test(Re const& re) {
    regex_match("abcd_ed123.t12y@haha.com", re);
}

static const std::regex std_normal("^[\\w._]+@\\w+\\.[a-zA-Z]+$");
static const std::regex std_optimized("^[\\w._]+@\\w+\\.[a-zA-Z]+$", std::regex::ECMAScript | std::regex::optimize);
static const boost::regex boost_normal("^[\\w._]+@\\w+\\.[a-zA-Z]+$");
static const boost::regex boost_optimized("^[\\w._]+@\\w+\\.[a-zA-Z]+$", static_cast<boost::regex::flag_type>(boost::regex::ECMAScript | boost::regex::optimize));

static const auto boost_xpressive = []{
    using namespace boost::xpressive;
    return cregex { bos >> +(_w | '.' | '_') >> '@' >> +_w >> '.' >> +alpha >> eos };
}();

NONIUS_BENCHMARK("std_normal",      [] { test(std_normal);      })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("std_optimized",   [] { test(std_optimized);   })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("boost_normal",    [] { test(boost_normal);    })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("boost_optimized", [] { test(boost_optimized); })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("boost_xpressive", [] { test(boost_xpressive); })
```

> **Note** Here's the output of the Hotspot JVM JIT compiler:
>
> - http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/fea76143-b712-4df9-97c3-4725b2f9e695/disasm.a.xz
>
> This was generated using
>
> LD_PRELOAD=/home/sehe/Projects/stackoverflow/fcml-1.1.3/example/hsdis/.libs/libhsdis-amd64.so ./jre1.8.0_171/bin/java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintAssembly Main  2>&1 > disasm.a

Comment: Try passing [`std::regex::optimize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type) to the constructor to force a FSA creation (in theory)

Comment: @Mgetz optimize makes the engine generate a DFA (deterministic finite automaton) instead of an NFA (non-deterministic finite automaton).  They're both Finite State Automata, but a DFA takes more effort to generate (although it will run faster and  cannot represent all regexes).

Comment: @Mgetz Or `optimize` does something else than we expect. Adding [clang+libc++](https://plot.ly/~sehe/19/). Also, for fun: comparative benchmark using GCC;libstdc++;Boost1.67: https://plot.ly/~sehe/21/ ([benchmark code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/FYn4nmfSZn/))

Comment: Added a Boost Xpressive [static regex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/xpressive/user_s_guide.html#xpressive.user_s_guide.creating_a_regex_object) into the mix. The Benchmark is still at only [<30 LoC](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hTJnC3WjFr/) and the results are still [clearly favouring Boost Regex](https://plot.ly/~sehe/23/)

Comment: @rustyx That was a good call. Adding `ECMAScript | optimized` made the optimized regexen slightly faster - making a bit more sense. [Updated the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50611867/revisions) (again).

Comment: Also the speed is implementation dependent, in my tests on arm64 clang on linux with full optimizations in release mode, I found that `libc++` regex implementation is about 16x faster than `libstdc++` one. And about 2x faster than boost version.

Answer (score 2):

As various commenters have pointed out it sounds like you are compiling your C++ code in `debug` mode which turns off many compiler optimizations and adds some extra diagnostic code to your program.

Since you are using Visual Studio 2017 look for the Solution Configuration drop-down and change it from `Debug` to `Release`.

[image: screenshot of Visual Studio 2017]